# Kubernetes Pod terminates with Exit Code 143

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, jvm, exit-code

I am using a containerized Spring boot application in Kubernetes. But the application automatically exits and restarts with exit code 143 and error message "Error".

I am not sure how to identify the reason for this error.

My first idea was that Kubernetes stopped the container due to too high resource usage, as described [here](https://komodor.com/learn/exit-codes-in-containers-and-kubernetes-the-complete-guide/), but I can't see the corresponding kubelet logs.

Is there any way to identify the cause/origin of the `SIGTERM`? Maybe from spring-boot itself, or from the JVM?

Answer (score 15):

> Exit Code 143

1. It denotes that the process was terminated by an `external signal`.
2. The number 143 is a sum of two numbers: 128+x, `# where x is the signal number sent to the process that caused it to terminate.`
3. In the example, x equals 15, which is the number of the `SIGTERM` signal, meaning the process was killed forcibly.

Hope this helps better.

Answer (score 4):

I've just run into this exact same problem. I was able to track down the origin of the `Exit Code 143` by looking at the logs on the Kubernetes nodes (note, the logs on the **node** not the pod). (I use [Lens](https://k8slens.dev/) as an easy way to get a node shell but there are [other](https://github.com/kvaps/kubectl-node-shell) ways)

Then if you look in `/var/log/messages` (I found it can be `/var/log/syslog` in some setups) for `terminated` you'll see something like this:

```
Feb  2 11:52:27 np-26992252-3 kubelet[23125]: I0202 11:52:27.541751   23125 kubelet.go:2214] "SyncLoop (probe)" probe="liveness" status="unhealthy" pod="default/app-compute-deployment-56ccffd87f-8s78v"
Feb  2 11:52:27 np-26992252-3 kubelet[23125]: I0202 11:52:27.541920   23125 kubelet.go:2214] "SyncLoop (probe)" probe="readiness" status="" pod="default/app-compute-deployment-56ccffd87f-8s78v"
Feb  2 11:52:27 np-26992252-3 kubelet[23125]: I0202 11:52:27.543274   23125 kuberuntime_manager.go:707] "Message for Container of pod" containerName="app" containerStatusID={Type:containerd ID:c3426d6b07fe3bd60bcbe675bab73b6b4b3619ef4639e1c23bca82692633765e} pod="default/app-comp
ute-deployment-56ccffd87f-8s78v" containerMessage="Container app failed liveness probe, will be restarted"
Feb  2 11:52:27 np-26992252-3 kubelet[23125]: I0202 11:52:27.543374   23125 kuberuntime_container.go:723] "Killing container with a grace period" pod="default/app-compute-deployment-56ccffd87f-8s78v" podUID=89fdc1a2-3a3b-4d57-8a4d-ab115e52dc85 containerName="app" containerID="con
tainerd://c3426d6b07fe3bd60bcbe675bab73b6b4b3619ef4639e1c23bca82692633765e" gracePeriod=30
Feb  2 11:52:27 np-26992252-3 containerd[22741]: time="2023-02-02T11:52:27.543834687Z" level=info msg="StopContainer for \"c3426d6b07fe3bd60bcbe675bab73b6b4b3619ef4639e1c23bca82692633765e\" with timeout 30 (s)"
Feb  2 11:52:27 np-26992252-3 containerd[22741]: time="2023-02-02T11:52:27.544593294Z" level=info msg="Stop container \"c3426d6b07fe3bd60bcbe675bab73b6b4b3619ef4639e1c23bca82692633765e\" with signal terminated"
```

The bit to look out for is `containerMessage="Container app failed liveness probe, will be restarted"`

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered similar problems too.

Because my program has scheduled task execution, I finally found out that a piece of my code was causing a memory leak by using Jmeter pressure testing locally and combining it with JProfiler.

As the program runs, the memory in the Eden area gradually decreases, and the Old area gradually increases until it reaches the maximum JVM heap memory, which finally triggers a container restart!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added the **spring-boot-starter-security** dependency to a shared common dependency of the service crashing.

This caused the default security filter to be configured which prevented kubernetes from reading the custom health check.

Since the health check kept failing the pod eventually got stopped externally.

Run the service locally and then query the health check to ensure you get 200 response codes from it.  If you get 401 then its likely this case.

I fixed my case by adding an  to the pom for **spring-security-config**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.something</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```